# TensorFlow - Different bit-width quantization between layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization

Does TensorFlow support different bit-width quantization between layers, or is it mandatory that the same technique is performed at the whole model?

For example, let's say I perform `16-bit` quantization at `n` layer. Can I perform `8-bit` quantization at `n+1` layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of now there is no option to define the different `dtype` for the different layers of a model.

As per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#arguments_1) of `tf.keras.layers.Layer`. This is the class from which all layers inherit.

> dtype - The dtype of the layer's computations and weights (default of
> None means use tf.keras.backend.floatx in TensorFlow 2, or the type of
> the first input in TensorFlow 1).